# Bitarray return same initial value

Tags: c#, bitarray

I need to make a sequence of BitArray (i.e chaining BitArray that each value depend on previous value)
also I need to manipulate each bit of each element in array of BitArray individually.
I have this segment of code  (NOTE that the functions of desion works in a correct manner)

```
     BitArray[] sub_keys=new BitArray[10000];
     for (int i = 0; i < sub_keys.Length; i++)
          sub_keys[i] = b;
            for (int i = 1; i < sub_keys.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 1; j <119; j += 8)
                {
                     {
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j, desion_105(sub_keys[i - 1], j));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 1, desion_150(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 1));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 2, desion_151(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 2));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 3, desion_152(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 3));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 4, desion_153(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 4));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 5, desion_154(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 5));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 6, desion_155(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 6));
                                sub_keys[i].Set(j + 7, desion_156(sub_keys[i - 1], j + 7));
                            }
                                                }// for j end

                }//for i end
```

the desion function segments is (all the same)

```
      public bool desion_150(BitArray ba, int index)
    {
        bool result;
        ........................// rest of code
        return result;

    }
```

My problem is the sub_keys always return same value (initial seed (b)).
I tried to fix the code but I failed, can anyone tell me where's the problem ??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A BitArray is a reference type. Your initialization loop uses the same instance over and over so they will all point to the same object instance.

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < sub_keys.Length; i++)
    sub_keys[i] = b;
```

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < sub_keys.Length; i++)
      sub_keys[i] = new BitArray(b);
```

...which will assign a separate, new instance to each element. By passing `b` to the constructor you set the new instance to a copy of `b`, which I believe is your intended behavior.